# How to implement multilevel accordion menu

Tags: jquery

I have a 3 level accordian Menu in my page. When the link in clicked in any level, the accordion is still open and the corresponding page is opened on the right side. [Woking page link](http://www.careeronestop.org/explorecareers/assessments/what-is-assessment.aspx)

[image]

Currently I am using JQuery and the XSLT. It supports three level, now I have to change it 5 level. Though the current implementation works, its bit complicated. So I would like to know, if anyone has implemented the same.

The links and titles are accssed through XSLT from the CMS and Jquery .

Comment: Implementation details aside, this seems like a UX nightmare.

Comment: @pygeek Why the question has been marked negative. I have a requirement for this and i am discussing the possibilities with the forum . You are more than welcome to suggest or leave it.

Comment: I wasn't the person who marked your problem as negative. It's probably marked negative because at first glance it seems like you're asking someone to do the work for you.

Comment: @pygeek Not asking someone to do the work. I have already implemented the 3 level navigation . Just need ideas or suggestion for adding more levels.

Comment: Can you provide your code and a demo on jsfiddle? Without them is a little complicated to help you

Comment: @IrvinDominin http://jsfiddle.net/yozgf5nk/3/ and the live is in http://www.careeronestop.org/explorecareers/assessments/interests.aspx

Comment: @IrvinDominin My code is XSLT and Jquery , I aslo attached the XSLT In the fiddle external resource

Comment: @Vani your code is quite a mess. You have open tags and no close tags and, as others have pointed out, your there is a page reload before the accordion can do anything. You don't need any javascript to accomplish this if you are happy to have page reloads between each click.

Answer (score 3):

```
<ul class="accordion-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="title">Explore Careers</a>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Set Careers</a></li>    
           <li><a href="#">Salaries</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#" class="title">Self assessments</a>
        <ul>
         <li>
          <a href="#">What is an assessment?</a>
         </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="clicked">Interest assessment</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Skills assessment</a></li>
          <li><a  href="#">Work values</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="#" class="title">Learn about careers</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Licenses</a></li>    
        <li><a href="#">Professions</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've added a new class `title` to identify accordion headers to avoid using slow child selectors.

And now in your `script`, add this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.title').on('click',function(){
      var $parent = $(this).parent();
      var $siblings = $parent.siblings();  
      $siblings.removeClass('active').find('ul').slideUp('normal');
      $parent.find('ul').slideDown('normal');
      $parent.addClass('active');
    });       

});
```

Also in this [live](http://www.careeronestop.org/explorecareers/plan/plan-your-career.aspx) page that you shared, they're refreshing the whole page to get the updated content. I suggest you use AJAX to get the updated content and then update that container instead of a doing a full page refresh. This will give a better user experience and also makes it easier for you to track the selected accordion without having to retain the state between page refreshes.

Here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9w52o0sy/2/) forked from yours with my changes. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Did u try adding level 4 and 5. Its not working for me.

Comment: Lv5 means 5 accordion headers or 5 links in each section ? The fiddle link i shared has 5 accordion headers and the same code works

Comment: I may not be clear in the question. Level 5 is not just the heading .. When you are in Level 3, it should able to navigate to  Level 4 from inside Level 3. While in level 4 ,you should be able to navigate to Level 5 .

Comment: See my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yozgf5nk/7/ when u click test - it will open level 4 and test 4 should open level 5. I m working on hiding the level 5 heading

Comment: Did u get the link. Also the onclick of the title should work for both slideDown and SlideUp. I am working on that as well

Comment: Let's discuss this on [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75735/accordion-issue)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75736/discussion-between-vani-and-arkantos).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you are trying to build a **nested accordion**.

Using **jQuery Tools** (http://jquerytools.github.io/demos/tabs/accordion.html) you can do this pretty easily. There is a **fiddle** (http://jsfiddle.net/Xanetia/8kz4m/) that demonstrates it so it would just be a matter of styling.

The big difference to your html is that instead of the structure you have:

```
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="title">Explore Careers</a>
      <ul>
         ...
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        etc.
```

You have:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h2>Explore Careers</h2>
    <div class="pane">
        <div class="accordion">
            <h2>Level 2 : 1</h2>
            <div class="pane">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2>Self assessments</h2>
    <div class="pane">
        etc.
```

**Alternative Solution:**

You may also want to look at [this jquery plugin off jqueryscript.net](http://www.jqueryscript.net/accordion/Smooth-Nested-Accordion-Plugin-with-jQuery-jQuery-UI-multiAccordion.html) (see the demo [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Smooth-Nested-Accordion-Plugin-with-jQuery-jQuery-UI-multiAccordion/))

Comment: thank you.. will try it. As u see my current working page, i need to retain the accordion open on the page refresh.

Comment: You could set a `current` class on each of the active `h2` tags and then use something like `$(".current").next().slideDown()`